# How to remove a character in some files in UNIX?

Tags: unix

I have a bunch of files in a folder, containing an undesirable special character (#) .

For one file, like `fadg0_si1279.acs` this seems to work, : `sed 's/#//' fadg0_si1279.acs > a.acs` , but in this case I have some difficulties for rewriting the source file: tried to write the target the same as the source: `sed 's/#//' fadg0_si1279.acs > fadg0_si1279.acs`, but it returns an empty file! everything is removed! any suggestion of why it happens, and how to fix it?

My next question: Is there any way to remove that character in the whole folder? It seems silly to do it one by one for 1340 files! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it recursively directories within directories and every file:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/#/2/g'
```

To do it in current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's/#//g'
```

- find - will find for file
- sed - will remove # inplace within the file and at the same sametime before replacing will create filename.bak file as well.

Answer (score 1):

In sed you can add -i to replace in-place:

```
sed -i 's/#//' file
```

Sed [man-page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed)

In perl this removes all # from all files in "Folder":

```
perl -pi -e 's/#//g' /Folder/*
```

Options Explain:
-p: Places a printing loop around your command so that it acts on each
    line of standard input. Used mostly so Perl can beat the
    pants off awk in terms of power AND simplicity :-)
-i: Modifies your input file in-place. Handy to modify files without the {copy,
    delete-original, rename} process.
-e: Allows you to provide the program as an argument rather
    than in a file. You don't want to have to create a script
    file for every little Perl one-liner.

the g stands for ALL recurrence of the simbol # in the files.